# Problema com pk que não existe ainda

Tags: django

Eu tenho a seguinte urls:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^proposal/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProposalDetail.as_view(), name='proposal_detail'),
url(r'^contract/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ContractDetail.as_view(), name='contract_detail'),
url(r'^proposal/edit/contract/$', 'create_contract', name='create_contract_url'),
```

Significa que existe eu tenho `/proposal/1/`,
mas no meu exemplo eu não terei `/contract/3/` ainda,
ou seja, `/contract/3/` é um contrato que não existe ainda,
e quando existir terá um `pk` que pode ser diferente de `proposal`.

```
# views.py
class ProposalDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'core/proposal/proposal_detail.html'
    model = Proposal
```

Para o `contract` existir eu irei executar a função a seguir...

```
def create_contract(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        proposal = Proposal.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if proposal.status != 'co':
            return HttpResponse('O status do orçamento deve ser concluido.')
        else:
            contractor = proposal.work.customer
            obj = Contract(
                proposal=proposal,
                contractor=contractor
            )
            obj.save()
            proposal.status = 'a'
            proposal.save()
    return redirect('/contract/%d' % obj.id)
```

... a partir deste botão.

```
# proposal_detail.html
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="." method="get">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'create_contract_url' proposal.id %}"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Criar Contrato</a>
</form>
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo controlar os `pk` da forma correta.

Pergunta: Como eu faço para melhorar este código de modo a informar o `pk` de `proposal` na função `create_contract`
e redirecionar a página para `/contract/3`, sendo que `3` será um novo `pk` de `contract`, mas ele não existe ainda?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvido.

```
@login_required
def create_contract(request, proposal_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        proposal = Proposal.objects.get(pk=proposal_id)
        if proposal.status != 'co':
            return HttpResponse('O status do orçamento deve ser concluido.')
        else:
            contractor = proposal.work.customer
            contract = Contract(
                proposal=proposal,
                contractor=contractor
            )
            contract.save()
            proposal.status = 'a'
            proposal.save()
    return redirect('/contract/%d' % contract.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que Contract possua uma ForeignKey de Proposal, você pode atribuir o valor no ato do salvamento, por exemplo:

```
#models
class Contract(models.Model):
    proposal = models.ForeignKey('Proposal', blank=True)

#views:
def create_contract(request, pk):
    proposal = Proposal.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = ContractForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.METHOD == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.proposal = proposal
            obj.save()
            return redirect('/contract/%d' % obj.id)

    return render(request, "seu_template.html", {'form':form, 'proposal':proposal})
```

Lembrando que não é muito sugestivo você utilizar o pk da url para duas coisas, no template você passou o id de proposal na url:

```
{% url 'create_contract_url' proposal.id %}"
```

E no redirect da sua view, você está retornando o id do contrato criado:

```
return redirect('/contract/%d' % obj.id)
```

É interessante que você se refira a uma coisa só em sua url, caso você queira os dois pk's, passe os dois pk's na url.

Se todo contrato se referir a um proposal, fica mais intuitivo que sua url de contrato seja dessa maneira:

```
url(r'^(?P<proposal_id>\d+)/contract/new/$', ContractCreate.as_view(), name='contract_create'),
url(r'^(?P<proposal_id>\d+)/contract/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ContractUpdate.as_view(), name='contract_edit'),
url(r'^(?P<proposal_id>\d+)/contract/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ContractDetail.as_view(), name='contract_detail'),
```

Respeitando a ideia do CreateView, UpdateView e DetailView, o sistema ficará muito mais legível.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#createview

Comment: Sim, mas não estou usando formulário, é apenas um botão que eu clico e executa a função.
Mas vc entendeu o que preciso sobre o id que não existe ainda do contrato?
Eu sei que baguncei um pouco os ids, mas eu preciso usar o pk de proposal apenas para me referenciar na hora de criar o novo contrato. E depois o redirect é para entrar no contrato novo, quando o pk dele existir.

Comment: Eu entendi, mas mesmo assim você pode utilizar as urls da forma que sugeri. Tanto no UpdateView quanto no DetailView, o default do django utiliza o "pk" para renderizar as informações de um objeto que já existe. Você pode utilizar a nomenclatura "proposal_id", no futuro isso até ajudará em manutenção de código. Na sua view ficaria def create_contract(request, proposal_id):
Fica mais intuitivo se você trabalhar dessa maneira.

Comment: Agora entendi. Obrigado.